# hdfs dfs -ls webhdfs:// not listing all files

Tags: webhdfs

When I run the following command it lists 91 files

hdfs dfs -ls /data

But when I use the follwing command it returns only 89 files

hdfs dfs -ls webhdfs://x.x.x.x:14000/data

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this issue in the last 3 years. I use this command almost every day. can you paste the missing files that from the webhdfs command and also what user is listing the files in both the cases and does this user have sufficient privileges to read the files?